# GhostScript dPDFSETTINGS shortcut

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, dpi

I'm very new to the GhostScript world and I was wondering what was the configurations that are setted when we write, for example, -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook?

The problem I face is that /ebook is too low quality and /printer is to heavy. I'm searching somewhere in the middle :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [the corresponding documentation](https://web.mit.edu/ghostscript/www/Ps2pdf.htm#Options), you probably want to set `ColorImageResolution` like this for instance if you want to tune image resolution:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -q -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dColorImageResolution=150 -o out.pdf in.pdf
```

You need to set `GrayImageResolution` or `MonoGrayImageResolution` for non coloured images.

Be aware that setting the resolution does not work if `PDFSETTINGS` is unset (respectively set to `/default`). I don't know why.

Comment: Use `-r<ressolution>` if you need to set the resolution of rasterized fonts (which you probably don't want to do).

Answer (score 0):

RTFM.

/ghostpdl/gs/doc/Ps2pdf.htm#Options

Then look for the big table with all the options listed in the rows, and the PDFSETTINGS listed in the columns. More usefully read up on all the Distiller parameters and select the ones you want to use.

Comment: Thanks. I read the fantastic manual, but I admit I asked the question because I have really no idea of what does what in all these settings. Of course I can test all one by one and figure out what value is best for each option. I was wondering where these values were hard-written (when we ask for /ebook) so I could just change this and that and, maybe, find more quickly  what I'm searching for.  Anyway, I will dig into that and hopefully find my happiness. Thanks for all

Comment: They have the same effect as the identically named Adobe settings, which are documented in "Adobe PDF Creation Settings", last seen at http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/pdf_creation_apis_and_specs/PDFCreationSettings.pdf The Ghostscript canned settings are defined in /ghostpdl/gs/Resource/Init/gs_pdfwr.ps. Note that if you are using the ROMFS then changing this will have no effect. You either need to alter the file and recompile or alter it and add the path to the modified file as an 'include' on the command line. eg -I/ghostpdl/gs/Resource/Init